# Trying to do an easy proof about countable sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'd like to prove that every time $\mathbb{Z}$ appears can be changed by $\mathbb{N}$. Seems intuitive enough for me, but I can't find a formal way to prove it.

Using $\mathbb{N}\sim\mathbb{Z}$ I proved particular cases separately, but I'd like to find a way to prove that this is always true without need to sketch a new proof for every new case (which includes $[0,1]^{\mathbb{Z}}, \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$, and all kind of possible cases). Also I'm assuming that it is true since as I said, seems intuitive, but is it?, can $\mathbb{Z}$ be changed by $\mathbb{N}$ no matter the case?.

Comment: I think some context is missing, otherwise $(2-3) \in \mathbb{Z}$ would not be true after the change to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @dtldarek: The cuestion is about countable and uncountable sets (as the title says), basically I'd like to know if any set that involves $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable/uncountable if for the same set we change $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{N}$. For example, $[0,1]^{\mathbb{Z}}$ countable $\iff$ $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ countable; $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ countable $\iff$ $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ countable and so on.

Comment: The word "involves" should probably be elaborated upon to reflect the kind of operations you are interested in. Let $$X(A) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{R}, & \text{if } A = \mathbb{N}, \\ \emptyset, & \text{if } A = \mathbb{Z}. \end{cases}$$ Then $X(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable, but $X(\mathbb{Z})$ is countable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use $\mathbb{Z}$ only in context of size, i.e. $|\mathbb{Z}|$ then yes, you can swap it with $\mathbb{N}$, because $$|\mathbb{Z}| = \aleph_0 = |\mathbb{N}|.$$

However, generally, you cannot swap it. If the simple example $(2-3) \in \mathbb{Z}$ does not convince you, consider the set of strictly decreasing sequences:

\begin{align} A_\mathbb{Z} &= \Big\{ (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\ \Big|\ 
(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ is a strictly decreasing sequence} \Big\}\\
&= \Big\{ (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\ \Big|\ 
\forall i \in \mathbb{N}.\ a_{i+1} < a_i \Big\}.
\end{align}

Observe that $|A_\mathbb{Z}| = 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{C}$, but for analogous definition of $A_\mathbb{N}$ we would have $|A_\mathbb{N}| = 0$, that is, an uncountable set becomes after the change empty (i.e. countable).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then taking the example I posted above, I could say that $[0,1]^{\mathbb{Z}}$ countable $\iff$ $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ countable because $|\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{N}|$?, there's no need of further proof or a further development is needed?; I ask because it seems to me that the set $\{f:f:\mathbb{Z}\to[0,1]\}$ is of the kind of your second example, so they coulnd't be swaped without proving that one is countable if and only if the other one is. Thanks!.

Comment: @Dante Take some bijection $\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{N}$ and adapt it to your case, e.g. let $f' : \{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z} \to \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ be defined as $f'(a) = (a \circ f^{-1})$. If your bijection doesn't break the properties you are using, then it will work (e.g. if you are not using any properties, then you can't brake them). On the other hand, there is no bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ that would preserve the standard ordering (i.e. the property of $\mathbb{Z}$ I am using in $A_\mathbb{Z}$), which is why the example in my answer does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can't change $\mathbb{Z}$ for $\mathbb{N}$ *all* the time; consider the statement $$\exists x\in \mathbb{Z}: x+2=0$$

When you reflect a bit more about the situations when you *can* swap the two, you will be closer to your answer, which is a bijection between the two sets.